# Disconnected Network Drive

Tags: windows-server-2003, networking, mappeddrive

We have a big problem that's just started happening.  One of our network apps (may it rot in hell) requires a mapped network drive to function.  Therefore, we map a drive to the network share in question for the users.  This usually shows up of course in Explorer as:

```
Sharename on 'Servername' (Q:)
```

Problem is, it now shows up as

```
Disconnected Network Drive (Q:)
```

And I can't remove it in any way

- **Right-click and select disconnect**: "The network connection could not be found"
- **CMD: net use q: /delete** - "The network connection could not be found."
- **CMD: net use \servername\sharename /delete** - "The network connection could not be found."
- **CMD: net use Q: \servername\sharename** - "The device is already in use"
- **Delete the user profile** - no change
- **Log in as new, never-logged-in-before user** - same problem
- **REG: delete HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MountPoints2##servername#sharename** - no change

Other items of note:

- Client machine is Windows Server 2003 R2 x86
- Server is Windows Server 2003 x86

Comment: Are your event logs showing any interesting or related entries?

Comment: Do you have a shortcut on the Desktop to that Q: ?
If yes, try to delete it. And use UNC paths.

Comment: @comarc This question is over 4 years old and already solved. Please read through the [tour](http://serverfault.com/tour) you skipped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, okay.  I think this might have been a vendor problem!

In case it should assist anyone else (I've seen this issue a few times on Google with various responses), I disabled all the new services installed by the vendor, and after a reboot all drives were fine.  It seems one of their services was mapping a drive in (.Net) code, and somehow *blocking* the network from then on.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what was the vendor of the problematic service? What kinds of things was it doing?

Answer (score 0):

I've had quite a few problems with mapped network drives disappearing over night and other issues. One thing I started doing was not using mapped network drives but referring to network paths using UNC notation e.g. `\10.1.1.1\sharename\path\file.ext`

Another issue I had was being told I was connected to a share when it wasn't listed from Windows Explorer. I had to use the `NET USE` command from the command-line to list, then delete, the offending connection.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts.  Unfortunately, as I mentioned in the OP, "don't use it" isn't an option (or a particularly useful one) and I've also tried the NET USE process already, as mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem as the OP that persisted with multiple users on the same workstation running Windows XP sp3. I did some poking around in the registry and found this: `HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\PostBootReminders\Microsoft.NetDriveReconnectFailed`.

This folder contained the following key/value pairs:

```
"Title"="Could not reconnect all network drives"
"Text"="Click here to open My Computer and see the status of your network drives."
"IconResource"="shell32.dll,10"
"ShellExecute"="::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}"
"ShowTime"=dword:00000000
"RetryInterval"=dword:00000000
"RetryCount"=dword:00000000
"TypeFlags"=dword:00000001
```

Of course, this is the text that appears in the information bubble when mapped drives can't reconnect.

When I deleted the `Microsoft.NetDriveReconnectFailed` folder and its keys from the registry (of course I exported them to a .reg file first), and rebooted the computer, the problem went away. Every user was able to map drives normally, and login scripts worked correctly.